# Display recordset based on query

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have been stuck on an for the last 2-3 days now. I have tried whatever I could find  online (Stackoverflow or otherwise). Desperately need help.

## Problem: Show a pop up with records based on a query.

I want this to be writable so that users can modify the records to remove the errors.

## Methods Tried So Far:

1. Method 1

```vb
    Dim rs_main As DAO.Recordset
    Set rs_main = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM PROMO_DETAILS_ERROR_TABLE WHERE ERROR_FLAG = -1 ORDER BY EVENT_NAME, ITEM_CODE, START_DATE, END_DATE")
```

2. Method 2

```vb
    Dim rs_main As DAO.Recordset  
    Dim strSQL As String  
    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM PROMO_DETAILS_ERROR_TABLE WHERE ERROR_FLAG = -1 ORDER BY EVENT_NAME, ITEM_CODE, START_DATE, END_DATE"  
    Set rs_main = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)`
```

3. Method 3

```vb
   Dim rs_main As DAO.Recordset  
    Dim strSQL As String 
    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef  
    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM PROMO_DETAILS_ERROR_TABLE WHERE ERROR_FLAG = -1 ORDER BY EVENT_NAME, ITEM_CODE, START_DATE, END_DATE"  
    Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("")  
    qdf.SQL = strSQL
    DoCmd.OpenQuery qdf 
    Set rs_main = qdf.OpenRecordset
```

4. Method 4

```vb
    Dim rs_main As DAO.Recordset  
    Dim strQ, strSQL As String 
    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef 
    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM PROMO_DETAILS_ERROR_TABLE WHERE ERROR_FLAG = -1 ORDER BY EVENT_NAME, ITEM_CODE, START_DATE, END_DATE"  
    Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef(strQ)  
    qdf.ReturnRecords = True  
    qdf.SQL = strSQL
    DoCmd.OpenQuery qdf  
    Set rs_main = qdf.OpenRecordset
```

## Current/Expected Result

See image for reference:

[image]

Appreciate your help!

Thanks,
Ana

Answer (score 3):

- Create a Form.
- Set the Form's `RecordSource` to be your query. This can either be a SQL SELECT command or it can be the name of a stored query.
- Add Fields to your form (select "Add Existing Fields" from the `Design` tab.

There is no need to script anything for this.

Or, if you have a stored query, you can simply open it with

```
DoCmd.OpenQuery "NameOfYourQuery", View:=acViewNormal
```

By "stored query" I mean a query that you created and stored in the query designer.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. For some reason, the OpenQuery did not work but changing the record source did. Thank you!